# Got "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument" when trying to add a IPv6 route

Tags: linux, router, ipv6, iproute2

When I try to add an IPv6 route I get an error message:

```
root@lx-anielsen ~ $ ip -6 route add ::a:6:0/112 via ::a:4:1 dev eth1.1001
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Here is what my interface configuration looks like:

```
root@lx-anielsen ~ $ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::92e2:baff:fe1f:a964/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::ea39:35ff:fe33:d2b8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::227:19ff:feb0:3cdf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth1.1001@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500
    inet6 ::a:4:2/112 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::227:19ff:feb0:3cdf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And my routing table:

```
root@lx-anielsen ~ $ ip -6 route
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
::a:4:0/112 dev eth1.1001  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev vmnet1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev vmnet8  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth4  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth1.1001  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
```

I'm using RHEL 6:

```
anielsen@lx-anielsen ~ $ cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 6.3 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those IPv6 addresses are indeed invalid. Use valid addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what's going on.

1) load the ipv6 module

`modprobe ipv6`

2) Add the ipv6 address and route

```
ip addr add 2001:IPV6:...2/64 dev eth1.1001
ip route add ::a:6:0/112 dev eth1.1001
```

3) give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Per Michael Hampton's comment you will commonly see this error message if you have an invalid IP/netmask combination.

Use a subnet calculator to double check that you have the correct netmask for your desired IP range and subnet size.